# Find the latest time in multiple columns and create a new column and populate the latest column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a new column based on the value of multiple datetime columns (first_test,second_test,third_test). I want to compare these column values and find the max value(latest date) and copy the column name in the new column(max_test)

```
emp_id    first_test         second_test               third_test
a123                  2023-01-19 12:31:00-06:00  2023-02-09 12:31:00-06:00
a321                  2023-02-09 11:43:00-04:30 
a543 
a211 2023-02-18 11:43:00-04:30 
a134 2023-04-23 16:33:00-03:40                   2023-01-09 11:43:00-04:30
```

My expected output is

```
emp_id   first_test         second_test               third_test               max_test
a123                  2023-01-19 12:31:00-06:00  2023-02-09 12:31:00-06:00  third_test
a321                  2023-02-09 11:43:00-04:30                            second_test  
a543      
a211 2023-02-18 11:43:00-04:30                                              first_test       
a134 2023-04-23 16:33:00-03:40                   2023-01-09 11:43:00-04:30  first_test
```

I tried in for loop but I am getting for null values.

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    first_date = test['first_test'][i]
    second_test_date = test['second_test'][i]
    third_test = test['third_test'][i]
    if second_test > third_test:
```

Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: Your a134 row doesn't make sense unless I'm misunderstanding your needs. 06-09 > 04-34, no? Therefore that row should have third_test under max_test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pd.DataFrame.idxmax to determine the index of the maximum value. Use axis=1 to specify you're grabbing the column index (name) for each row. This returns a pd.Series which you can set as an additional column in the DataFrame.

```
df["max_test"] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

df['max_dt'] = df[['first_test', 'second_test', 'third_test']].max(axis=1)

This should grab max date while creating a new column in your dataset. Or if you want to use a variable in the field like above run this code and create a dataset then do a case statement that matches the emp_ID and max date with empl id and your date columns.